# How can I add "borough names" to this code in SQL Postgres (Pgadmin)?

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT borocode, SUM (totpop), SUM (sq_miles)
, SUM (totpop) / SUM (sq_miles) pop_density_pr_sqm 
FROM public.uscb_acs_14to18_age
GROUP BY borocode
```

This code only shows borocode, I want it to show the borough names as well

Answer (score 0):

You may use an aggregate function like `max` as "parasitic"

```sql
SELECT borocode, max(boroname), SUM (totpop), SUM (sq_miles)
, SUM (totpop) / SUM (sq_miles) pop_density_pr_sqm 
FROM public.uscb_acs_14to18_age
GROUP BY borocode;
```

or add `boroname` to the group-by list of expressions.

```
SELECT borocode, boroname, SUM (totpop), SUM (sq_miles)
, SUM (totpop) / SUM (sq_miles) pop_density_pr_sqm 
FROM public.uscb_acs_14to18_age
GROUP BY borocode, boroname;
```

If `borocode` is the primary key of the table then it is not even necessary to list non-aggregated expressions in the group-by list.